# Django getting related foreignkey fields confusion

Tags: django, many-to-many

I am unable to give a proper title for the problem I am having. I'll try to explain it as much as I can.

I have 2 models College and Course. College has many to many relationship with course. I also have a model called College_Specific_Course_Details which has college and course as the foreign keys and an extra attribute called "Fee".

I am able to add college, course and college_specific_course_details from the backend. In the front end I have a requirement where I have to list all the courses of a particular college and its fee. It is because a particular course can have different fee in different colleges even if the course content is same.

I am able to list courses with college.courses.all in the template, but I have problem getting fee of courses in the specific college. I am confused as what is the correct way to doing it? I have read in several places that passing arguments through a template tag is not recommended. I am unable to figure out a way to show it.

My template tag goes like this:

```
<h3>Courses</h3>
                        {% for course in college.courses.all %}
                          <li>
                             <a href="{{ course.get_absolute_url }}">{{ course.title }} 
                                      {{ something here should pull the fee of this course in this college }}
                             </a>
                          </li>
                        {% endfor %}
```

My Models are as follows:

```
class College(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class CollegeSpecificCourseDetails(models.Model):
    college =ChainedForeignKey(College)
    course = ChainedForeignKey(Course)
    monthly_fee = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: You should show your models.

Comment: I added the models as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DanielRoseman said, you really need to show your models. But it sounds like your confusion is rooted in having both a `ManyToManyField` between `Course` and `College`, and a separate `College_Specific_Course_Details` table. If I'm understanding you correctly, these are redundant. Instead, make `College_Specific_Course_Details` your M2M table by using the [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) keyword.

It might look something like this:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    # some fields

class College(models.Model):
    # some fields
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, 
                                     through='CollegeCourse', 
                                     related_name='colleges')

class CollegeCourse(models.Model)
    college = models.ForeignKey(College, related_name='college_courses')
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='college_courses')
    fee = models.IntegerField()
```

Then you can iterate like so:

```
{% for college_course in college.college_courses.all %} 
    {{ college_course.course.id }}
    {{ college_course.fee }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you for the help. but the thing doesn't show up. I have modified my question with added edits for Models. I did what you said as well, but it looks like adding through in ManyTOManyField requires removal of the field from ModelAdmin fieldset, which is not the motive. I need field to add courses in the college admin.

Answer (score 0):

Ok keep many to many field relation as you wish :).
Just loop over  CollegeSpecificCourseDetails object to get college,course and fees

```
college_course = CollegeSpecificCourseDetails.objects.all()
for college_course_detail in college_course:
    college = College.objects.filter(id=college_course_detail.college_id)
    course = Course.objects.filter(id=college_course_detail.course_id)
    fee = college_course_detail.monthly_fee
```

Comment: Thank You. I need the course field as ManyToMany in the college model because I am migrating old content to Django, which needs to migrate old relationships as well.

Comment: check out if you can use  above edited logic to get college,course and fee